# Enabling Auditing on Azure SQL Server (V12) breaks ADO.NET connection

Tags: sql-server, azure, auditing

In an attempt to do some basic profiling on our Azure SQL Server (V12) we enabled Auditing using the Azure portal.

Not many seconds later I had an angry developer on my hands that could not connect to the database using his client (HTML5 page).

I really couldn't see the connection, but since enabling auditing was the only change, I tried disabling Auditing again, and sure enough now the client could connect.

Further info:
I could access the SQL server using SSMS just fine.
The problem was only on the TEST environment from the customers network, not from our DEV environments (which is from Visual Studio on the developers own laptops).

Can anyone tell me why enabling auditing can break this? We tried doing it on other databases too, and sure enough: when I enabled auditing, the connection could not be established...

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-auditing-and-dynamic-data-masking-downlevel-clients/), if you want auditing on, the FQDN connection strings need to be changed:

Original server FQDN in the connection string: (server name).database.windows.net

Modified server FQDN in the connection string: (server name).database.**secure**.windows.net